# Any constraints to refer to the high half of a register in gcc inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly

In my C code there are some inlined assembly calling PCI BIOS service. Now the problem is that one of the results is returned in the `%ah` register, but I can't find a constrant to refer to that register.

What I want is to write like following:

```
asm("lcall *%[call_addr]" : "something here"(status) :);
```

and the variable `status` contains the value of `%ah` register.

If I use `"=a"(status)` and add a `mov %%ah, %%al` instruction it will work. But it seems ugly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to specify `%ah` in a constraint - the GCC x86 backend knows that sub-registers contain particular parts of values, but doesn't really treat them as independent entities.

Your approach will work; another option is to shift `status` down outside the inline assembler.  e.g. this:

```
unsigned int foo(void)
{
  unsigned int status;

  asm("movb $0x12, %%ah; movb $0x34, %%al" : "=a"(status) : );
  return (status >> 8) & 0xff;
}
```

...implements the `(status >> 8) & 0xff` as a single `movzbl %ah, %eax` instruction.

A third option is to use a small structure:

```
unsigned int bar(void)
{
  struct { uint8_t al; uint8_t ah; } status;

  asm("movb $0x12, %%ah; movb $0x34, %%al" : "=a"(status) : );
  return status.ah;
}
```

I'm not sure whether this is nicer or not - it seems a little more self-documenting, but the use of a small structure with a register constraint looks less obviously correct.  However, it generates the same code as `foo()` above.

(Disclaimer: code generation tested with gcc 4.3.2 only; results may well differ on other versions.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried both of your solutions before this post. For your third option I used a union instead, which I think will have a better looking. A common problem of these walkarounds is that they require extra code, making a wrapper function quite long. I think have to keep my current method before a better one is found.